Open README.md in preview when project is opened
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/60061
Has this feature been removed? My README.md's are not opened and I can find no setting to enable it.
I'd like for the feature be generally enabled. In the package.json so it will apply for all users opening the project if that is even possible.
If feature was pulled is there another way to do this?

There is a workbench.startupEditor setting, and you can select the readme as an option:
{
   "workbench.startupEditor": "readme"
}


It seems no other editors can be left open from previous sessions  for it to open the readme however.  If you set this as so, close all editors, and open a folder that contains a readme, it should open it in the preview mode.

As Timothy has said, the current implementation of "workbench.startupEditor": "readme" is that it will only open the readme's markdown preview if no other editors are restored when opening the workspace, which should generally be the case for people opening the workspace for the first time. If you want a different behaviour, you should raise a feature-request issue ticket.

I'd like for the feature be generally enabled. In the package.json so it will apply for all users opening the project if that is even possible.

If anything, it'd be workspace settings.json. Not package.json. And if you read the description of that value for the workbench.startupEditor setting, t very clearly says:

Note: This is only observed as a global configuration, it will be ignored if set in a workspace or folder configuration.

As for why, I don't know.

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.
